# Does Laragon ignore .htaccess?

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, xampp, laragon

I'm trying to move a working project from XAMPP to Laragon.

Everything is fine, but some directives I've put in my `.htaccess` don't work anymore: all modules seems to be enabled correctly.

What I'm trying to have working again is the versioning for my assets:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c|rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(css|js)$ $1.$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is placed in the root of the project with `Laravel`, but moving it into the public folder does not change anything

In the Apache config I have the following correctly uncommented:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And this is the host configuration (untouched)

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/projectski/public/"
    ServerName projectski.localhost
    ServerAlias *.projectski.localhost
    <Directory "C:/laragon/www/projectski/public/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see it points to `/public`, but moving to the root (which I would like to, considering server configuration) will disable everything and turn the local site into a directory.

Please help me move to Laragon.

Comment: Change all `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All` in file `httpd.conf` in my case its `C:\Laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15\conf\httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for an answer, **Laragon does not ignore .htaccess**

The error was a simple syntax error in the `IfModule`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c | rewrite_module>
    # Logic
</IfModule>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, still throwing 404 error